# Using jQuery to check for regular expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email-validation

I know there's the jQuery validation plugin. But I don't need something that extensive.

All I want to do is have jQuery check a name text box:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
```

To make sure that it has at least 2 characters

AND

I want jQuery to check a phone text box (identical to the name text box, name="phone" and id="phone"), to make sure that it only contains numbers, doesn't matter how many numbers.

Finally, and this is only if this is not too hard to accomplish, I want jQuery to validate the email address to check and make sure that it has the character '@' in it.

Is this too hard to do?

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: For your first validation, you really don't need any plugin. It's like `$('#name').val().length > 2`. But for the other two, you should look for a plugin. Unless you consider "`@@.Foo`" as valid email.

Comment: For these purposes, yes, let's consider @@.Foo as a valid email, as well as dslfjdsjfskj@djfkjdsalfkjdsalk, as well as a@a. For email validation, it must be longer than 3 characters and must contain the '@' character. Is this hard to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the jQuery validation plugin is too extensive, here's an [even simpler one.](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/rsv/jquery/demo.php)